# Is it possible to access hidden instance fields in PHP as in Java?

Tags: java, php

In Java as in PHP, instance fields declared in parent classes are inherited in child classes. Therefore, it is possible to access them using the keyword `this` (resp. `$this` in PHP).

In Java, if the child class happens to declare a field with the same name as the parent class, the parent class's field is *hidden* (see [JLS 8.3.1.1-3: Hiding of Instance Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12172)). It is there, but if the child class wants to access it, it needs to use the keyword `super`, as in the following example:

```java
class Foo {
    protected int x = 1;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected int x = 2;

    void somemethod() {
        System.out.println(this.x); // prints 2
        System.out.println(super.x); // prints 1
    }
}
```

Please note that I consider hiding fields as a bad practice, as it only makes for confusing code and easily leads to logic bugs. It is best not to declare instance fields with the same name as an instance field of a parent class. Therefore, this question is of a purely academic nature.

Nevertheless I am curious: Is it in principle possible to access hidden instance fields in PHP, as is possible in Java? Would it be possible to translate the above code snippet to PHP?

```php
<?php

class Foo {
    protected $x = 1;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected $x = 2;

    function somemethod() {
        echo $this->x, PHP_EOL; // prints 2
        //echo $parent->x, PHP_EOL; // doesn't compile... is there a way to do it?
    }
}
```

Please note that I am talking about *instance* variables here. Class (i.e., static) variables are a different story altogether and are not a subject of this question.

If it is not possible: Does this mean that the parent instance field effectively gets *overwritten* in PHP (instead of just hidden), and is thus inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working for you, is because you are overriding the parent. `Foo->$x` is available in the child scope, therefor when you define `X` as `2` in `Bar` it overrides the previous set variable.

If you want something like this to work like in Java, then you would have to use constants.

```
class Foo {
    const x = 1;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    const x = 2;

    function somemethod() {
        echo parent::x; // prints 1
        echo self::x; // prints 2
    }
}
```

Or you could simply change the variable name in `Bar` and then you would have direct access to it through inheritance.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this does not directly answer my question. There isn't anything that is "not working" for me. It is a purely academic question and my examples are constructed just for that purpose. :-) I am simply curious as to how overriding of instance fields is implemented in PHP. Obviously, it is possible with static fields (as declared by `const`), which is why I stated that my question is about instance (not static) fields. And of course, when changing the name of the variable we don't get into this type of problem at all.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa You're answering your own question if you already knew about changing the variable name. The instance gets overridden, hints why the variable becomes two when it has the same name. I also answered your question in my post, aswell as providing you with the code that would allow you to use PHP classes like in Java. In PHP `parent` is equivalent to `super`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Unfortunately, I am afraid you misunderstand my question. Just to be sure: Do you clearly understand the difference between *instance* fields and *static* fields?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Mate, your question is clearly `Does this mean that the parent instance field effectively gets overwritten in PHP (instead of just hidden), and is thus inaccessible?` which I already told you, it does. Instance fields are object specific, and when you extend a class and use the **same** name for the variable, it gets overridden. Unlike static variables / methods where you can use the parent variables etc.

Comment: Exactly, instance fields relate to an object, while static fields related to a class. Now, citing from my question: `"Please note that I am talking about *instance* variables here. Class (i.e., static) variables are a different story altogether and are not a subject of this question."` Now your answer is basically: `"You can use static variables!"`, which is precisely what this question is explicitly not about. Therefore it appears you misunderstood the question. Again, my question is (citing from the title): "Is it possible to access hidden *instance* fields in PHP as in Java?".

Comment: PS. At any rate, I do appreciate your efforts! :-)